# Simluating an ARMA Model Using R

Tags: r

My professor and I who are new to time series analysis in `R` are attempting the simulate an ARMA model. However, we are having trouble understanding where the parameters for the time series simulation come from. When simulating an ARMA model in `R` using the `arima.sim()` function, one argument that is required in the function is model =, which is a list with component ar and ma giving the AR and MA coefficients respectively. The issue we are running into is that we do not know where these AR and MA coefficients come from. Would anyone happen to know where the coefficients arise from?

I have tried searching the internet for information regarding this issue. However, the only answer that I have seen is that the coefficients are from
running an ACF and PACF. Though, there has been no further explanations as to what we are running the ACF and PACF over to generate these coefficients. Are we running ACF and PACF over previously simulated data or something else?

## AR(1) Model Example Code

```
Ar.sm <- list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.1, sd = 0.1)
Ar.lg <- list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.1, sd = 0.1)

AR1.sm <- arima.sim(model = Ar.sm, n = 50)
AR1.lg <- arima.sim(model = Ar.lg, n = 50)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if anyone has found any literature or videos explaining this more in depth, that would be fantastic. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: This one isn't bad -> <https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-forecasting-with-arima-in-r-learn-data-science-tutorials>. Might be worth stackexchange rather than here because your question is less about code and more about a how to

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What ARMA process are you trying to simulate?  If you have a specific one in mind, you can use those parameters. If your ARMA process is a model for data, you can fit the model to that data and use those fitted parameters. Or do you want a sample from *any* ARMA process and you don't care which one?

Answer (score 0):

The ARMA model is actually a *class of models* where you get different models by using different parameters.  If you are using an ARMA(p,q) model then this means you have p auto-regressive (AR) terms and q moving-average (MA) terms.  The AR and MA coefficients in the model set the size of these terms.  If you are merely *simulating* a model (as opposed to making inferences from data) then it is up to you to set the coefficients to whatever values you want to simulate with.  You are correct that different coefficient values give different kinds of results that are closely connected to the ACF and PACF.

Since you are simulating, may I suggest that you just try to simulate some examples using coefficients of your choice, and vary the coefficients you put into your simulation to see the differences in what you get out.  It would also be a useful exercise for you to construct the sample ACF and PACF of your simulated data, and see how these vary as you change the coefficient values going into your simulation.  This will give you a better idea of the connection between the coefficients and the output of the model.